# Little owl as decoy for skylark

Tags: ornithology, ethology

I read that hunters used (now is forbidden) little owls tethered to attract skylarks.
They say this is due to their magnetic look of the eyes.

I didn't find any scientific documentation of this. Any one knows a scientific explanation of this, if any? Why, if true, should the skylark be attracted by the owl?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reference. Skylarks react to the presence of the owl to mob it.

Van Nieuwenhuyse, Dries; Genot, Jean-Claude; Johnson, David H. (2008). The Little Owl: Conservation, Ecology and Behavior of Athene noctua. Cambridge University Press. p. 6. ISBN 978-0-521-71420-4.